# Assign value on the right side

Tags: f#

I am learning F# and I have the following code:

```
type Name = {first:string; last:string} // define a new type
let bob = {first="bob"; last="smith"}   // define a value 

// single parameter style
let f1 name =                       // pass in single parameter   
   let {first=f; last=l} = name     // extract in body of function 
   printfn "first=%s; last=%s" f l

// match in the parameter itself
let f2 {first=f; last=l} =          // direct pattern matching 
   printfn "first=%s; last=%s" f l 

// test
f1 bob
f2 bob
```

My background is imperative programming and the value assignment works like this:

```
f = first
```

but the code above assigns value on the right side using

```
first=f
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here - F# is not assigning a variable, you are pattern matching.

The syntax here follows from how you would create a record as you are pattern matching to it - note the similarity between:

```
let f2 {first=f; last=l} =
```

and

```
let bob = {first="bob"; last="smith"}
```

and a more extreme example:

```
let f3 {first="bob"; last="smith"} =
```